# Stuck In login loop after updating my system to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, xubuntu, ubuntu-one

I updated my system from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and after updating when I am starting my machine it's asking me for login password and when I am typing the correct password one blank screen appears and it's again asking me for the password and the same thing happening again and again. I saw some answers on the internet for this problem and everyone says to press Ctrl + Alt + F1 on login screen to enter into console and follow some commands as they mentioned but whenever I am pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 or F2,F3,.....,F9 nothing is happening and I can't see any console and I am still on the login page. Please help me guys to get rid of this problem. I will be very happy if you can help me

Comment: To test, do you have another account that you can try to log into? Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Also, do you use a Nvidia video card? If so, did you also update your Nvidia driver?

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for login loops...

If you've been starting graphic applications from the terminal using `sudo`, that's what probably caused your problem. Always use `sudo -H`.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw

  - `cd /home/your_username` # change directory

  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown your_username:your_username .*thority*` # change file ownership
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.